# running isolines-isochrones notebook example

Tags: python, osmnx

I installed osmnx on a Linux terminal via Anaconda following the installation instructions from osmnx readthedocs, but when running the example from GitHub isolines-isochrones
(https://github.com/gboeing/osmnx-examples) I get the followinf error:

```
AttributeError
center_node =  ox.distance.nearest_node(G, x[0], y[0])
G = os.project_graph(G)
AttributeError: module 'osmnx.distance' has no attribute 'nearest_nodes
```

I tried calling get_nearest_nodes but it throws a different error related to _api.py.
The problem is the installed version, the one I have installed calls for methods get_nearest_nodes instead of nearest_nodes. nearest_nodes seems to be from a later version replacing the deprecated get_nearest_nodes but it's not the default version that gets installed. I don't know how to install the correct version of osmnx, the one that it is actually used in the repository examples, any help would be appreciate it.

Comment: File a bug ticket, because the example has a bug. However, inspect the code yourself, maybe you can even include a fix.

Comment: I think you need to update osmnx. In the previous version, the function was unavailable.

Comment: You appear to be using a very old version of OSMnx. Upgrade to the latest to use the latest features demonstrated in that notebook.